# Сохранение файла перед выходом

Tags: c#

Подскажите код, который будет выдавать сообщение перед выходом из программы, что в файл были внесены изменения, с запросом на сохранение.

P.S Текстовый редактор.

Comment: просто отслеживайте во время работы вашего редактора, изменялся ли  в нем текст, в том числе с учетом отмененных действий. Конкретный код тут давать бессмысленно

Comment: С моими минимальными, если так можно выразиться, знаниями лучше объяснять на примере кода.

Comment: вы предлагаете мне написать вам тут текстовый редактор с сохранением изменений?

Comment: Нет, только функцию выхода, с ее условиями, если файл был изменен, то сохранить/отменить/вернуться назад к тексту. Редактор я основной написал, с трудом, но сам.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм примерно такой.

Заведите флаг, который будет указывать, были ли изменения в файле. При загрузке документа флаг должен быть сброшен (то есть равен **false**) - вполне логично, что едва открыв документ, вы в нем еще ничего не изменили.

Далее следует помнить, что флаг может быть сброшен или установлен в случае любого изменения документа. Способов изменить может быть четыре (поправьте, если ошибаюсь):

1. изменение путем ввода/удаления текста с клавиатуры;
2. изменения путем вставки-вырезания текста;
3. изменения форматирования текста;
4. изменения путем отмены/возврата предыдущих изменений.

Первые три вида изменений должны устанавливать флаг в **true** - все они предполагают, что  полученный текст будет отличен от исходного. Однако четвертый тип изменений (отмена/возврат  предыдущих изменений) предполагает, что документ может быть возвращен в исходное состояние. В этом случае (если конечно у вас в редакторе предусмотрены Undo/Redo) потребуется запоминание шагов, точнее, того шага, который возвращает документ в исходное состояние. /По достижении этого шага флаг также сбрасывается в **false**. При всех остальных шагах флаг будет равен **true**

Ну и последним, о чем надо упомянуть - флаг должен сбрасываться при сохранении документа.
Код приводить не стану - для корректной демонстрации работы этого механизма его понадобится слишком много. Но в целом все достаточно просто.

З.Ы. очень плохой идеей является решение "в лоб" - сравнивать текущее содержимое файла со старым при малейшем его изменении. Если при маленьких размерах документов это еще может как-то работать, то в случае с большими документами могут возникнуть серьезные тормоза